# Click to Update Database, from editable QAbstractTableModel

Tags: c++, qt

An editable table view is connected to a custom model (a subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`) that populates it from a database. The table view's edited values are temporarily held in a 2D `QVector`.

The goal is for a push button below the table view to trigger an update of the database.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out the `SIGNAL`&`SLOT` mechanism for this. It seems to be a problem of the scope of the push button, I think, but I don't know how to fix it.

First two files just for overview, the problem is (probably) in the **third, in `setData()`**.

I'm still a beginner in this framework so apologies for a potentially silly question.

- a tableView("*menuTable*") and a pushButton("*menuTableUpdateButton*") are made in Design Mode.
- mainwindow.cpp *(opening a db conection, querying db, placing result into QVector and initializing and assigning the model)*

```
...
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow) 
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

     //database connection
     ...
     //opening database
     if(db.open())
          {
          ...       
          //2D array to hold the query to pass into model        
          QVector< QVector<QString> > sqlQueryVector; 
          ...
          //querying and storing the result
          ...        
          //initialize QAbstractTableModel and pass it into the menu table
          //passing an id(int) and a 2D QVector that holds the sql query result to the model
          menuTableModel* modelMenu = new  menuTableModel(id, sqlQueryVector);
          ui->menuTable->setModel(modelMenu);        
          }
     else
          {
          ...
          }
}
```

- menutablemodel.h *(basic initializations)*

```
#ifndef MENUTABLEMODEL_H
#define MENUTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QVector>

class menuTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit menuTableModel(const int &monId, const QVector< QVector<QString> > &qry, QObject *parent = 0)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent), mondayId(monId),query(qry) {}

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex & index) const ;
    void setQuery(const QVector< QVector<QString> > &query);
    void setId(const int &stId);

private:
    int mondayId;
    QVector< QVector<QString> > query;

signals:
    void editCompleted(const QString &);

slots:
    void updateDatabase();

};
#endif // MENUTABLEMODEL_H
```

- menutablemodel.cpp *(assigning data into table, editing and SAVING TO DATABASE)*

```
#include "menutablemodel.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>

int menuTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const {...}

int menuTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const  {...}

QVariant menuTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {...}

QVariant menuTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {...}

//edit and save into database
bool menuTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role)
{
if (role == Qt::EditRole)
{
    query[index.row()][index.column()] = value.toString();        
    QString result;
    for(int row= 0; row < query.size(); row++)
    {
        for(int col= 0; col < query[0].size(); col++)
        {
            result += query[row][col] + " ";
        }
    }
    emit editCompleted( result );
     qDebug() << "result is: " << result;

    //update database here with connect??
    //connect(menuTableUpdateButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (updateDatabase()));


    }
    return true;
}


Qt::ItemFlags menuTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex & /*index*/) const {...}

void menuTableModel::setQuery(const QVector< QVector<QString> > &qry) {
    query = qry;
}

void menuTableModel::setId(const int &stId) {...}

void menuTableModel::updateDatabase() {
   //write SqlQuery here  
   ...
}
```

My main question is where and how do I define the `SIGNAL`&`SLOT` command to connect the button being clicked to executing an SQL query to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainWindow` constructor, you have the model and the button, so that's the best place to connect them:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
 : QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow) 
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

     //opening database
     if(db.open()) {
          //...   
          menuTableModel* modelMenu = new  menuTableModel(id, sqlQueryVector);
          ui->menuTable->setModel(modelMenu); 

          // Connect button click to model update
          connect(ui->menuTableUpdateButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                  modelMenu, SLOT(updateDatabase()));

      }
}
```

Comment: That absolutely works. Scope gets a little confusing to me still, I was mulling this over all day. Thank you so much!